# How to get a line break in a plain text email RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, plaintext

I'm sending a plain text email and was wondering how I add a line break to this.  It's showing up on on the same line.

```
From: <%= @name %>
<%= @text %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\r\n
```

or if you're sending html email:

```
<br />
```

so:

```
From: <%= @name %> \r\n <%= @text %>
From: <%= @name %> <br /> <%= @text %>
```

Comment: This may work on some systems but is not technically correct. New lines in plain text emails should always be CRLF ("\r\n"): [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html)

Comment: This isn't working for me. At least not in the Rails 4.1 mailer preview (I haven't viewed a sent email). I'm using Haml and have `\r\n` on its own line. [Renders like this.](http://i.imgur.com/uCbtB2t.png)

Comment: \r\n should be inside <%= %> and in double quotes - <%= "\r\n" %>. Otherwise it's considered as simple text

Comment: And if you're using HAML and @SergiiMostovyi's suggestion, use #{'\r\n'}

Answer (score 16):

```
<%= "\r\n" %>
```

In double quotes and inside '<% %>'.

Otherwise it's considered as simple text.

Comment: And if you're using HAML use #{'\r\n'}

Answer (score 2):

I could be completely wrong, but isn't it a simple \n ?

Comment: I'm seeing the literal \n characters in my emails (with no line breaks at all). It looks like they were converted from line breaks to \n

Answer (score 0):

If your template is in HAML, some_template.text.haml, you can use the \ char:

```html
= t(".salutation_start", name: name)
\
= t(".paragraph.text")
\
\
= t('.salutation_end')
\
= t('.contacts')
```